# Change ordered list style in Jupyter notebook

Tags: css, markdown, jupyter-notebook

I want to change the "bullets" (whatever one calls them) for the ordered lists in my Jupyter notebook. I've tried putting the following in `~/.jupyter/custom/custom.css`, but it doesn't make a difference:

```
ol {list-style-type: lower-alpha}
```

I've tried adding `.rendered_html` as a CSS selector too, but it didn't help.

I want to type, in a markdown cell, something like:

```
1. First item
2. Second item
```

and have, instead of

1. First item
2. Second item

something like

a) First item

b) Second item

(except actually as an ordered list). How can I achieve a different "bullet" in the ordered lists generated from Markdown in Jupyter notebook cells?

Comment: and what if you add `!important` ?

Comment: Ah, I should have tried that; that works. I thought that, since `custom.css` should come after all other styles, it would have precedence already. If you want to make an answer from your comment, I'll accept it. (Bonus if you can tell me how to get 'a)' instead of 'a.'; I'm not very good at CSS).

Comment: even if it's after you need to keep specifity into consideration ;) and for the `a)` there is no predefined option but here is a workaround with pseudo element https://jsfiddle.net/1vw58gb8/1/

Comment: Hm, that sort of works. Did you bold the ')' so that one doesn't notice the '.' is still there as well? Maybe I'll just settle for 'a.' then. Thanks!

Comment: yes :) but it was a very quick workaround, we can have a more clean if you need it ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use

```
{<ul>
<li>the first unordered item</li>
<li>the second unordered item</li>
<li>...</li>
</ul>}
```

- the first unordered item
- the second unordered item
- ...

and it will be presented by bullet listed. However, it does not work for Jupiter notebook or GitHub text editor. Find more on
- https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_list-style-type_all

Comment: This doesn't answer the question; I know how to write lists, but I wanted to change the CSS to use a different type of "bullet" for the ordered lists, specifically in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Ok, I suppose you need to define classes for each bullet type. [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: https://www.tutorialandexample.com/css-lists/